# orthogonal projections and polynomial density

Tags: general-topology, matrices, functional-analysis, polynomials, lp-spaces

Which of the following statements are true?

$(a)$ Let $n\geq 2$. The set of all matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ which represent orthogonal projections is closed in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

$(b)$ The set  of all polynomial functions are dense in the space $L^1(]0,1[)$.

I tried to show that the preimage of the set of all orthogonal projection matrices is closed under some continuous map. But couldn't define one. For $(b)$, I think it has to do something about polynomial approximations of $L^1$ functions. But I'm not sure. So, how to proceed this one?

Comment: For (b) think Weierstrass approximation.

Comment: I thought about it, but couldn't reach a conclusion with $L^1$ functions. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: For (a), consider the maps $P\mapsto P^{2}-P$ and $P\mapsto P^{*}(I-P).$ $P$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if it has a very special image under both of these maps.